# iOS Enterprise Developer Program rules

Tags: ios, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

Trying to get head around the iOS Enterprise Developer Program and whether the following conditions are allowed...

I have an app on the app-store which is used by many businesses and an individual company has come to me, wanting their own specific version of this, tailored for them.

The iOS Enterprise Developer Program seems the way to go. However, I'm wondering about the issue as I am not an employee or contractor of theirs.

I could become a 'contractor' and can build ipa's for them under their own certification, as discussed in quite a few places in this forum.

My issue is that the source-code is not theirs. I will retain the rights to everything and they will just receive an ipa for distribution.

So my question is whether this is allowed under the iOS Enterprise rules? It would seem odd that it's not but a contractor normally develops programs for and on behalf of that company, with the company retaining the source code. In my case, the 'angle-of-attack' is different and I can't see anywhere where this is either allowed or disallowed.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why should Apple care? certificate owners don't have to be source owners...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Apple [iOS Enterprise Program FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.php) You can't use iOS developer program. However you can be a contractor and your cilent needs to enroll iOS Enterprise program and add the appropriate developer.

> I am a contractor who wants to create an in-house app for my client.
>   Can I join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program to do that? No. The
>   iOS Developer Enterprise Program is for companies/organizations to
>   develop and distribute proprietary in-house apps to their employees.
>
> Your client should enroll in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program and
>   add the appropriate developers from your company to their iOS
>   Development Team.

AFAIK You are the owner of the code. Program is not meant for ownership of code or any license.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was really after 'reassurance' I suppose and was also looking to see if anyone else practices with this relationship with companies. Your comment has confirmed my thoughts.